# VMNET0 is missing from virtual network editor of vmware workstation 10

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have installed VMware-workstation-full-10.0.3-1895310 on windows 8.1. Although VMware brige protocol is enabled in my LAN adapter but still I am unable to add and switch VMNET0 to bridged mode.

[image]

It says "Cannot change network to bridged: There are no unbridged host network adapters"

[image]

So far I have tried the following things:

1. I have reinstalled it many times
2. I have restore default settings of virtual network editor
3. Have also checked that Vmware bridge protocol is enabled
4. Have checked that whether vmnetbridge service is running or not

[image]

5. have done almost everything present on forums

Comment: I had the same problem with VMWare 12.0. Upgrading to 12.5 sort of fixed it: vmnet0 is visible in the virtual network editor, but only when it is running in UAC admin mode. My VM's can connect bridged again though, also without UAC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same problem also. I also run Kaspersky AV, and tried bigapple99's suggestion and unticked `Kaspersky Antivirus NDIS 6 filter`. This made the NIC show up in the editor, but didn't fix the problem. I noticed I was running the editor as Administrator when it was showing up, so I tried running VMWare Workstation as Administrator too. It worked! I tried reticking the Kaspersky filter, and reopening VMWare Workstation as Administrator, and it still works :) Best of both works, I'll just Run as Administartor now.

[image]

Comment: Although I don't face this problem anymore because I no longer have my old computer with me. But your solution seems correct because I have't tried running it as Administrator

Comment: This was the only answer that fixed my problem.  vmnet0 still doesn't show up in ipconfig, but the bridging now works when VMWare is run as Administrator.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after upgrading windows 10. "Repair" VMware workstation version fixed the problem. I'm using VMware Workstation 11.1.3.

Comment: This worked for me using VMware Workstation 12.5.6 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

It's wired in network editor the "Bridged To" showing nothing in the drop down list (at least it should show "Automatic"). Can you try to untick the Kaspersky Antivirus NDIS 6 filter in LAN property to see whether your NIC will show up in the editor?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem today and I thought I'd come back to you since no one answered your post yet.

My problem was coming from Kaspersky AV.

1. Remove VMWare
2. Remove Kaspersky AV
3. Re-Install VMWare
4. Re-Install Kaspersky

Hope it'll be of some help.
Best,
Alex